# Remote Filtering Based on JSON Attributes in Geomesa HBase

Tags: hbase, illegalargumentexception, geomesa

I'm trying to run a query that filters based on json attributes against a Geomesa HBase cluster with remote filtering enabled (`hbase.remote.filtering = true`). However, the query is failing due to an `IllegalArgumentException` with error message `Property '$.featurePayload.properties.user' does not exist in feature type`. Is there a way to enable remote filtering based on json attributes with Geomsa and HBase?

Note: I was able to run this query successfully when `hbase.remote.filtering` was set to false and the filtering was done on the client side where the application connects to a GeoTools DataStore to get the features by query. My main confusion is what is different on the remote filtering that is throwing the exception and if there is anyway to get json attribute filtering remotely working.

This is an example query I am trying to run:

```
\"$.featurePayload.properties.user\" = 'someUser'
```

This is the table schema:

```
INFO  Describing attributes of feature 'OSMNodes'
geometry           | Point     (Spatio-temporally indexed)
ingestionTimestamp | Timestamp (Spatio-temporally indexed)
nextTimestamp      | Timestamp 
serializerVersion  | String    
featurePayload     | String
```

Example feature in the table:

```
id,*geometry:Point:srid=4326,ingestionTimestamp:Timestamp,nextTimestamp:Timestamp,serializerVersion:String,featurePayload:String
1789928211#3165330648,POINT (-0.1844331 27.2077326),2019-12-23T03:00:00.000Z,9999-12-30T23:59:59.000Z,geojson,"{""geometry"":{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[-0.1844331,27.2077326]},""id"":""3165330648"",""properties"":{""tags"":{},""changesetId"":123456,""version"":1,""uid"":1111111,""user"":""someUser"",""featureSource"":""OSM"",""sourceTimestamp"":""2014-11-03 19:40:40"",""ingestionTimestamp"":""2019-12-23 03:00:00""}}"
```

Stack trace:

```
1. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property '$.featurePayload.properties.user' does not exist in feature type 
2.  at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.factory.FastFilterFactory$$anonfun$1.apply(FastFilterFactory.scala:263)
3.  at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.factory.FastFilterFactory$$anonfun$1.apply(FastFilterFactory.scala:263)
4.  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
5.  at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.factory.FastFilterFactory.property(FastFilterFactory.scala:262)
6.  at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.visitor.QueryPlanFilterVisitor.visit(QueryPlanFilterVisitor.scala:139)
7.  at org.geotools.filter.AttributeExpressionImpl.accept(AttributeExpressionImpl.java:347)
8.  at org.geotools.filter.visitor.DuplicatingFilterVisitor.visit(DuplicatingFilterVisitor.java:118)
9.  at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.visitor.QueryPlanFilterVisitor.visit(QueryPlanFilterVisitor.scala:318)
10.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.visitor.QueryPlanFilterVisitor.org$locationtech$geomesa$filter$visitor$QueryPlanFilterVisitor$$bind(QueryPlanFilterVisitor.scala:351)
11.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.visitor.QueryPlanFilterVisitor.visit(QueryPlanFilterVisitor.scala:150)
12.     at org.geotools.filter.IsEqualsToImpl.accept(IsEqualsToImpl.java:149)
13.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.visitor.QueryPlanFilterVisitor.visit(QueryPlanFilterVisitor.scala:81)
14.     at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:45)
15.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.factory.FastFilterFactory$.optimize(FastFilterFactory.scala:412)
16.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.factory.FastFilterFactory$.toFilter(FastFilterFactory.scala:401)
17.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.iterators.IteratorCache$$anonfun$filter$2.apply(IteratorCache.scala:82)
18.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.iterators.IteratorCache$$anonfun$filter$2.apply(IteratorCache.scala:82)
19.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.cache.ThreadLocalCache.getOrElseUpdate(ThreadLocalCache.scala:68)
20.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.iterators.IteratorCache$.filter(IteratorCache.scala:82)
21.     at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.filters.CqlTransformFilter$.deserialize(CqlTransformFilter.scala:286)
22.     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you verify that the `featurePayload` attribute has a user data flag set for `"json"` -> `"true"`? You should be able to see that by scanning the catalog table through the hbase shell.